# what should I write on server.conf when try create VPN on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, openvpn

I use CentOS 7 . I want to create VPN server on my machine. I am following perfect VPN tutorial until I get to this part, editing `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`:

```
local x.x.x.x
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh2048.pem
plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server ?  ?
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS ?"
push "dhcp-option DNS ?"
keepalive 5 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status server-tcp.log
verb 3
```

There are a few parts I don't understand.  Please explain for me how it works.  There are a lot of tutorials on the internet, but they just type their own network so I don't understand anything.

This is my local network information: [http://imgur.com/a/cgJkW](https://imgur.com/a/cgJkW).

What should I type for the `?`s ?

- Where i can find DNS to type on `push "dhcp-option`?
- Where I can find the IP to type on `server`?

Am I doing it right? What do I have to fix?

Comment: Please try to use better formatting in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The "server" line is only needed on the client config; it tells the client what server to talk to.

The DNS entries are the IP address of the DNS servers you want the client to use.  If you don't need to use specific DNS entries (eg no "internal DNS" on your network) then you don't need to push any DNS values at all.

Comment: i can't except that answer.

Comment: Can you explain a very little step, where do I find the DNS IP to type? what command? Just find and type, that is. And server too.

Comment: thats not correct. `remote` is used to specify the server's address and port in the client config

Answer (score 0):

Write for example:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

This is where you define the subnet for your OpenVPN network. You can't find it somewhere, you choose it. The above will serve a `/24` subnet, the vpn server's IP will be `10.8.0.1`, the first client `10.8.0.2`. Check out the [manpage](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage) for more information. This directive will expand as shown on the manpage:

> `--server network netmask ['nopool']` A helper directive designed to simplify the configuration of OpenVPN's server mode. This directive
>   will set up an OpenVPN server which will allocate addresses to clients
>   out of the given network/netmask. The server itself will take the ".1"
>   address of the given network for use as the server-side endpoint of
>   the local TUN/TAP interface. For example, `--server 10.8.0.0
>   255.255.255.0` expands as follows:
>
> ```
>  mode server
>  tls-server
>  push "topology [topology]"
>
>  if dev tun AND (topology == net30 OR topology == p2p):
>    ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
>    if !nopool:
>      ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.4 10.8.0.251
>    route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
>    if client-to-client:
>      push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
>    else if topology == net30:
>      push "route 10.8.0.1"
>
>  if dev tap OR (dev tun AND topology == subnet):
>    ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
>    if !nopool:
>      ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.254 255.255.255.0
>    push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"
>    if route-gateway unset:
>      route-gateway 10.8.0.2
> ```

To push dns server configuration to your clients write for example:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

Or for example if you decide that you want your clients to use the google's dns servers:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

A basic example `server.conf` file without any special configuration will look like this (I removed all optional directives, which should not be required in a very basic setup):

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 60
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status server-status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: Ok , I get it. But can you see this my problem: http://imgur.com/a/PB2Zm, and help me, please.

Comment: I just try to fix it again, but it still not working.

Comment: @hiroshi17, the problem has to do with your first line `local`. either wrong ip or the port is already in use. you don't need `local`. remove it and the server will bind to all adresses.

Comment: I think the local x.x.x.x is public Ip address?

Comment: With `local x.x.x.x` you specify the IP on which the server should listen. This should be one of the IPs listed with `ip addr | grep inet`, then the server will only listen on that IP. You can also omit this directive, then the server will listen on all IPs of all interfaces. Check also that the port is not already in use with `netstat -an | grep 1194`.

Comment: Can you help me write correct all again in file server.conf?

Comment: @hiroshi17, I added an example server.conf file.

Comment: why i see so many server.conf so diferrent on all website create vpn tutorial. which one is rightest ?

Comment: is i have to add "push router gateway"?

Comment: is I have to add" user nobody , group nobody" ?

Comment: i see they add "ifconfig ....." . what is this about?

Comment: @hiroshi17, This depends on what you want to do. If you want all your clients traffic to be redirected through the vpn server, then you have to specify `push "redirect-gateway def1"`.

Comment: There are so many ways to setup OpenVPN, so I can not know what your detailed configuration should look like I recommend you to read the [manpage](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage), this will help you to understand what directives you need to accomplish your goals. I had the same problem when I tried to understand OpenVPN just with looking at tutorials. But finally after reading the manpage, I started to understand it and I felt much better. Also a good point to start is the official [howto](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html).

Comment: Use the manpage to check this, type in your terminal: `man openvpn` then on the manpage to search for the explanation of this directive, type: `/--ifconfig` + ENTER. Search again by pressing the `N` key.

Comment: is i have to add "server-bridge x.x.x.x"?

Comment: what is "push "route "?

Comment: is it away is def1 in push "redirect-gateway def1". Is have to change that name?

Comment: `server-bridge` is for using `tap` interface. No `def1` is written as is. See manpage: def1 -- Use this flag to override the default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.